# Trying To Get Similar Username From Six Different Files

Tags: python, json, web, web-scraping

I have scraped six different people's followers list from instagram and trying to get the usernames of people that are same in all six accounts but so far it is not accurate so any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code to open and read through json files with followers list and sort them in a dictionary according to their first two letters and compare them

```
import json

with open('./JSONs Old/A.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    A = json.load(f)
with open('./JSONs Old/B.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    B = json.load(f)
with open('./JSONs Old/C.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    C = json.load(f)
with open('./JSONs Old/D.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    D = json.load(f)
with open('./JSONs Old/E.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    E = json.load(f)
with open('./JSONs Old/F.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    F = json.load(f)
with open('./JSONs Old/G.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    G = json.load(f)

Als = {}
Bls = {}
Cls = {}
Dls = {}
Els = {}
Fls = {}
Gls = {}

# Loop For A
for each in A:
        if each['id'][:2] in Als.keys():
             Als[each['id'][:2]].append(each)
        else:
            Als[each['id'][:2]] = [each]

# Loop For B
for each in B:
        if each['id'][:2] in Bls.keys():
             Bls[each['id'][:2]].append(each)
        else:
            Bls[each['id'][:2]] = [each]

# Loop For C
for each in C:
        if each['id'][:2] in Cls.keys():
             Cls[each['id'][:2]].append(each)
        else:
            Cls[each['id'][:2]] = [each]

# Loop For D
for each in D:
        if each['id'][:2] in Dls.keys():
             Dls[each['id'][:2]].append(each)
        else:
            Dls[each['id'][:2]] = [each]

# Loop For E
for each in E:
        if each['id'][:2] in Els.keys():
             Els[each['id'][:2]].append(each)
        else:
            Els[each['id'][:2]] = [each]

# Loop For F
for each in F:
        if each['id'][:2] in Fls.keys():
             Fls[each['id'][:2]].append(each)
        else:
            Fls[each['id'][:2]] = [each]

# Loop For G
for each in G:
        if each['id'][:2] in Gls.keys():
             Gls[each['id'][:2]].append(each)
        else:
            Gls[each['id'][:2]] = [each]

matchls = []
for i in B:
    if (i['id'][:2] in Als.keys()) and (i['id'][:2] in Cls.keys()) and (i['id'][:2] in Dls.keys()) and (i['id'][:2] in Els.keys()) and (i['id'][:2] in Fls.keys()) and (i['id'][:2] in Gls.keys()):
        matchls.append(i)

print(matchls)
```

The Json files have list of all the followers a person have on their instagram page and list container two key value pairs like following

```
[
  {
    "name": "Name1",
    "id": "username1"
  },
  {
    "name": "Name2",
    "id": "username2"
  }
]
```

i want to check if id from one file is in other five files too.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What problem are you having? Does your solution work? How is it deficient? Do you suspect part of it? When asking questions for code that relies on data, it is important that a minimal example of the data is included in your question.  The easier you make it for *us* to copy and paste from your question (so that we can execute your code and test our solution) the more likely you'll get responses. - Please read [mre].

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it without sorting:

Using this function you can see if a follower's id is in any other json lists

```
# (param 1) follower: a single dict with including a key 'id'
# (param 2) follower_lists: list of loaded json files to check an id match
def compareFollowers(follower, follower_lists):
    for list in follower_lists: # loop through each json file
        if not any(follower['id'] == f['id'] for f in list): # check if the id is the same as another from the list
            return False # if there is no common ids, return False

    return True # if every list had a common id return True
```

FYI The `any()` function returns a `boolean` value:

- `True` if at least one element of an iterable is true
- `False` if all elements are false or if an iterable is empty

to print all common followers between all files you can do this:

```
import json

with open('./JSONs Old/A.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    A = json.load(f)
with open('./JSONs Old/B.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    B = json.load(f)
with open('./JSONs Old/C.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    C = json.load(f)
with open('./JSONs Old/D.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    D = json.load(f)
with open('./JSONs Old/E.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    E = json.load(f)
with open('./JSONs Old/F.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    F = json.load(f)
with open('./JSONs Old/G.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    G = json.load(f)


follower_lists = [B, C, D, E, F, G] # include every list but the first

for follower in A: # loop through the first list and compare each follower's id
    if compareFollowers(follower, follower_lists):
        print(follower)
```